# Joining two results in a servlet and sending it to JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, orm, javabeans

I have two SQL tables: `Agency` and `Reservation` where `agency_id` is the primary key of the first table and the foreign key of the second. Then I have a jsp page where I want to display all reservations, but instead of showing `agency_id` I would like to show `agency_name`.

The thing that confuses me is that I have JavaBean class `Agency.java` and the other class `Reservation.java` that are mapping the fields of the mentioned SQL tables.

Now, how do I send over an object from servlet to jsp that represents a join of these two SQL tables? Because both of these JavaBean classes have their own constructors and what I need is a "hybrid" object. Do I need to create a third JavaBean that represents this hybrid object? Please advice. Also note that I don't want to use SQL in jsp in order to replace `agency_id` with `agency_name` on the fly.

I've searched all over the internet and can't find the appropriate solution because my search results are always with Hibernate framework or irrelevant to my problem.

If you need code samples I'm willing to provide. Thanks so much in advance for your replies.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? You could make a view that joins both tables before they are sent to JSP view.

Comment: Hi @Marcin I'm using mysql. Isn't JSP already a view?

Comment: Oh you mean DB view, I thought you were referring to MVC. Honestly, I would prefer the solution to be done in Java code rather than in DMBS. But thanks anyway. cc:@Marcin

Comment: Why? DBMS queries are way more efficient than processing the same in Java, they are designed to do things like that. You need actually just one JOIN query, that is all.

Comment: I already have a JOIN whether in Java or in DBMS is irrelevant to my question because with JOIN I get a hybrid object (mix of columns from 2 tables) and my question is how to store that object (should I create a third JavaBean class)